# pushed branch not visible on github

Tags: git, github, branch

I've made some changes and to a branch, commit them and pushed it but I still don't see the branch (nor the commits) on github (or can't pull changes to another machine).
What I've tried already:

```
$ git branch       *MyBranch
                   main
$ git push         Everything up-to-date
$ git branch -vv   *MyBranch 76e9e79[origin/MyBranch] last commit message
$ git status       On branch MyBranch
                   Your branch is up to date with 'origin/MyBranch'.
$ git remote show origin MyBranch    tracked
      Local branches configured for 'git pull':
      MyBranch merges with remote MyBranch
      main                     merges with remote main
    Local refs configured for 'git push':
      MyBranch pushes to MyBranch (up to date)
      main     pushes to main                     (up to date)
```

What's going on, why is `MyBranch` not visible on github nor available for pulling on another system?

In response to @ElpieKay's comment:

```
$ git remote -vv
origin  git@github.com:org/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:org/repo.git (push)

git push origin MyBranch:MyBranch
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: Does `origin` refer to the Github repository? How about `git push origin MyBranch:MyBranch`?

Comment: @ElpieKay Thanks for the reply, please see the update above!

Comment: Is `76e9e79` the commit that you have made for the changes?

Comment: yes, I can confirm withw `git log -1`

Comment: If you make a new clone on the current system, is it possible to check out the branch and see the commit?

Comment: This all looks fine. Perhaps there's some sort of temporary glitch at GitHub.

Comment: @torek can I force push it?

Comment: If `git push` says "everything up to date", it means *they already have it*. Force-push will have no effect. A more interesting question is: what part of GitHub's system is claiming that they *don't* have it, when the part that receives from your `git push` to `origin` (i.e., `git@github.com:org/repo.git`) says that they *do* have it.

Comment: In other words, break this thing down into parts. Suppose you were calling your company's main switchboard and asking for the phone number for your own office. If you call that phone number directly (from your cell phone perhaps), that phone actually *rings*, and it all works fine. But the switchboard says that you don't work there, even though you're sitting right there, in your office, working. Obviously the problem is at the *switchboard*, not in your office. Your Git is able to call up their Git and deliver the commits; their Git says "oh yes, I already have those, we're all fine".

Comment: Since their *Git* is working just fine, any problems you're having must be somewhere else.

Comment: I understand that but am wondering how I best can find and fix this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start over from scratch, get a fresh clone and copy across the files I've changed.... luckily the changes are manageable in size.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and `git push origin mybranch` was the solution. `git push` didn't push the branch to GitHub. But then I tried `git push origin mybranch`, on the hunch that `origin/mybranch` hadn't been created yet. Then git showed the branch uploading and `mybranch` appeared on the GitHub website.